# Does there exist a shortcut in Google Chrome to close all open Incognito Windows, but not all open Chrome windows?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, private-browsing

Suppose one is browsing on Chrome on a regular window, but there is also an (or many) Incognito window(s) open in the background. The user does not want to open them and close the windows one by one, but he or she is also unwilling to close all windows. [Ignore the question of the motivations of the user. This is a purely hypothetical scenario.] In such a case, does there exist a shortcut in Chrome by which he or she may close all Incognito windows without opening and closing them one by one, but no regular windows?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to close all incognito tabs through a keyboard shortcut is to go to the incognito window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

If you want an extension which closes the current window, and opens another window with an empty new tab, you can use [Close All Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-all-tabs/ghcmiphoepcihlmphakgmpapfpldlleg) in order to close a window by clicking the extension's button.

Answer (score 1):

For those who do not really need a shortcut but just want an easy built-in (no extention) way to close all Incognito windows, you can just click Incognito windows counter and then click on "Close Incognito".

That will close all Incognito windows that may be open on any of the Windows virtual desktops, so you do not need to hunt them manually.

Closing all Incognito windows will make Chrome properly forget all stored cookies in any of those windows. Next time you open new Incognito window it will start with a clean session.

[image: Close all incognito windows]

Answer (score 0):

I use an extension to deal with that named ["Close Incognito Windows - Keyboard Shortcut"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-incognito-windows-k/igkgeedjebclacnkomeopdhkgimkhned).

Then just use alt + w